# UITableViewCellEditingStyle doesn't show red/green minus sign circles

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have code working that allows the user to edit some items in the table (including delete and inserting new) when pressing the standard edit button.

It all works as expected (I can delete with swipe and an add button appears when "edit" is pressed), except that no red/green circles show up even when I'm in the correct editing style mode.

Following is my table editing code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    tableData = ptrBookmarks;

    numberOfSections = 1; // for editing: initial number of sections

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    //allow row selection during editing.
    //if the "Add Row" row is selected we can trigger an insert.
    //rather than forcing the using to click the (+) icon directly
    self.aTableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES;
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.

    if ([self isEditing]) // the current view is in editing mode, return count + an extra row
        return [tableData count] + 1;
    else // return count
        return [tableData count];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }

    //if number of rows is greater than the total number of rows in the data set
    //and this view is in editing mode.
    //Initialize the cell for "Add Row"
    //there will be an extra row once SetEditing: is called
    if(indexPath.row >= ptrBookmarks1.count && [self isEditing]){
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Add Row";
    }
    else {
        cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    return cell;
}


//VIEW CONTROLLER METHOD: IMPORTANT
//this is a method of the view controller
//if we use apple's editing button as follows:
//self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
//then this method will be called automatically for us.
//if we are using a button callback or similar method,
//then we need to call setEditing: manually on the view
-(void) setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated{

    //wrap our code in an if statement
    //only run the code if we are not swipe deleting a row.
    //if we were called due to a swipeDelete action, ignore it
    if(isSwipeDeleting == NO){
        //call parent
        [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];


        //if editing mode
        if(editing){
            //batch the table view changes so that everything happens at once
            [self.aTableView beginUpdates];
            //for each section, insert a row at the end of the table
            for(int i = 0; i < numberOfSections; i++){
                //create an index path for the new row
                NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:tableData.count inSection:i];
                //insert the NSIndexPath to create a new row. NOTE: this method takes an array of paths
                [self.aTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[path] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            }
            //animate the changes now
            [self.aTableView endUpdates];
        }else{
            //batch the table view changes so that everything happens at once
            [self.aTableView beginUpdates];
            //for each section, insert a row at the end of the table
            for(int i = 0; i < numberOfSections; i++){
                //create an index path for the new row
                NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:tableData.count inSection:i];
                //insert the NSIndexPath to create a new row. NOTE: this method takes an array of paths
                [self.aTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[path] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            }
            //animate the changes now
            [self.aTableView endUpdates];
        }
    }
}


//DELEGATE METHOD:
//this method will be called for every row and allows us to set the
//editing syle icon(Delete,Insert)
-(UITableViewCellEditingStyle) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    // Detemine if it's in editing mode
    //if (self.editing) {
    //use the + icon(add icon) on row
    //if this is the additional row created in setEditing:animated:
    if(indexPath.row >= tableData.count){
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert;
    }
    else{
        //use the delete icon on this row
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
    }
    //}
    //else
    //return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}

//handle the deletion insertion
//this method is called when the delete or insert icon has been press.
//we should update our dataSource by inserting or removing the selected INDEX
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        //remove row from datasource
        [tableData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        //remove the row in the tableView because the deleteIcon was clicked
        [self.aTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    }
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        //add a new row to the datasource
        [tableData addObject:@"New Icon"];
        //insert a row in the tableView because the plusIcon was clicked.
        [self.aTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]
                               withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    }
}


//if we are in editing mode we do not want to perform Seque Transition
- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender {
    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"MyDetailView"] && [self isEditing]) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}


//this method is called when the user swipes to delete a row.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    isSwipeDeleting = YES;//user just swipe to delete a row
}
//when the user cancel the swipe or click the delete button
//this method is call
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    isSwipeDeleting = NO;//swipe to delete ended. No longer showing the DELETE button in cell
}



// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {

    NSString *item;

    item = [[tableData objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row] retain];
    [tableData removeObjectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
    [tableData insertObject:item atIndex:toIndexPath.row];

    [item release];
}




// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

//DELEGATE METHOD:
//the user selected a row
//In order for the user to perform an INSERTION action on a row,
//they have to click the + icon icon. We can implement this method
//so that they can click anywhere on the add row to add a new row
//tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES; must be set
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //deselect the selected row with animatiion
    [self.aTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    //if the selected  row was the "Add Row" row call tableView:commitEditingStyle:
    //to add a new row
    if (indexPath.row >= tableData.count && [self isEditing]) {
        [self tableView:tableView commitEditingStyle:UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert forRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
    else { // otherwise do regular table item selection
        [self.delegate didTapBookmarksTable:[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue. I had to add `[aTableView setEditing:editing];` to the `setEditing` function because I'm using UIViewController instead of UITableViewController.